# How to make squid proxy to accept self-signed certificate?

Tags: kubernetes, squid, self-signed-certificate

I have an use-case were I have to accept self-signed certificate in Squid.
The endpoints are Kubernetes clusters using self-signed certificates. The clusters will be recreated on demand with different self-signed certificate and therefore the need to accept them with a regexp, preferred way, or globally for test purpose.

The current Squid version is 6.0.0, compiled with the follow flags:

```
Squid Cache: Version 6.0.0-VCS                                                                                                                                             
Service Name: squid                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                           
This binary uses OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018. For legal restrictions on distribution see https://www.openssl.org/source/license.html                                        
                                                                                                                                                                           
configure options:  '--prefix=/apps/squid' '--enable-icap-client' '--enable-ssl' '--with-openssl' '--enable-ssl-crtd' '--enable-security-cert-generators=file' '--enable-au
th' '--with-default-user=proxy'
```

In my tests I played with the ssl_bump configs and the tls_outgoing_options:

```
http_port 8080 ssl-bump cert=/apps/squid/etc/ssl_cert/CA_crt.pem key=/apps/squid/etc/ssl_cert/CA_key.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB 
sslcrtd_program /apps/squid/libexec/security_file_certgen -s /apps/squid/var/logs/ssl_db -M 4MB
sslcrtd_children 5
ssl_bump bump all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
tls_outgoing_options options=ALL flags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER,DONT_VERIFY_DOMAIN
```

But the best result I can achieve is `_curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name`

Or without ssl_bump

```
http_port 8080 ssl-bump cert=/apps/squid/etc/ssl_cert/CA_crt.pem key=/apps/squid/etc/ssl_cert/CA_key.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB
sslcrtd_program /apps/squid/libexec/security_file_certgen -s /apps/squid/var/logs/ssl_db -M 4MB
sslcrtd_children 5
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
tls_outgoing_options options=ALL flags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER,DONT_VERIFY_DOMAIN
```

I Get `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to`

Today I need K8S endpoints but tomorrow can be any other endpoints, therefore the need to make squid create the connection tricking the CN may be.